# One click event to do different things

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I only want:

```
$('.div_rightColumn').fadeOut("fast");
$('.div_rightColumn').fadeIn("fast");
```

to run on the first click.  Is there a way to tell jQuery to only do that the first time it is clicked and only run:

```
$('.name_filter img').live("click", function() {
      $('#contactMessage').fadeOut();
      $('.div_rightColumn').css({"margin" : "3px 0 0 0"});
});
```

the rest of the clicks?  Below is full...

```
$('.name_filter img').live("click", function() {
      $('#contactMessage').fadeOut();
      $('.div_rightColumn').fadeOut("fast");
      $('.div_rightColumn').fadeIn("fast");
      $('.div_rightColumn').css({"margin" : "3px 0 0 0"});
});
```

Comment: You should never use live(). Live makes things slower, you cant unbind, and its only in there for legacy reasons. Use delegate instead: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var run = 0;
$('.name_filter img').live("click", function() {
      $('#contactMessage').fadeOut();
      if(run === 0){
           $('.div_rightColumn').fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast");
           run++;
       }
      $('.div_rightColumn').css({"margin" : "3px 0 0 0"});
});
```

Also, as I said in the comment above you should really, really change your live to a delegate like:

```
$('.name_filter').delegate("img", "click", function() {
     //code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen for an event only once, you can use .one

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: It answers his/hers question 50%.

Comment: Yeah, also, `once()` is great, but I prefer to use variables in case, for whatever reason, later on you want to dynamically reset it. If you use once you'll have to recreate the element.